# Let $(I − A)^2 + A = 0,$ and suppose that the inverse of the square matrix $A$ exists. Write down a formula for $A^{−1}$ in terms of $A$

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I have tried everything in my knowledge and couldn't get a grasp of what the answer should be. Only thing that remains is a booklet formula for A^-1 = adj(A).1/det(A) but that doesn't make sense as it doesn't use the first equation. Can you give me some insight?

Comment: $I-A+A^2=0,$ so...

Comment: You don't need to assume $A$ has an inverse.

Comment: Thank you for editing it. I've realised that i don't know algebra operations in matrices . Will learn now.

Comment: If Thomas's hints are not enough, remember $B$ is an inverse of $A$ if $AB = I$ and $BA = I$ (though, if $A$ is square, one or the other suffices). See if you can use your equation to find such a $B$ (as a function of $A$).

Comment: So my solution goes as follows. ***A = A^2 +I*** ;;; ***AA^-1=A^2A^-1 + IA^-1***;;; ***I = A + A^-1*** which means that inverse of A is equal to I - A

Comment: @sam $A^{-1} = I - A$ is correct, but beware of the step where you multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. In that step, you assume that $A^{-1}$ exists! If you proceed like Laba Sa, and imply show that $A(I - A) = I$ (and/or $(I - A)A = I$), then this suffices to show that $I - A$ is a (necessarily unique) inverse of $A$ by definition, *proving* that $A^{-1}$ exists, and that it must be $I - A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(I-A)^2+A=0$ $\implies I^2+A^2-2A+A=0$ $\implies A^2-A=-I \implies A^{-1}=I-A$